# Get More Apps by developer

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing an iOS app and I have a section "More Apps" in the app, where I have to display all the apps of the developer on itunes.

Similar like:

I have tried using itunes Search API, but couldn't get an expected result.

Can any one has idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: I think the only way to show this information inside your app is to `hardcode` the apps or fetch a list of them from your own server.

Comment: Here: https://github.com/danielamitay/DAAppsViewController

Comment: Is this allowed by Apple? I thought you weren't allowed to show other apps within your own app like that. I will stand corrected if someone can convince me otherwise.

Comment: You are allowed. Apple even provides a class in the Store Kit framework to show contents of the app store in your apps. Anyway, the Search APIs work fine, you just need to search for your vendor id or name.

Answer (score 0):

Besides comments above, you could simply jump to App Store.app for searching Apps by the artist name, using this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/[artist name]"]];
```